# Для чего нужно двоеточие в квадратных скобках?

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис

Для чего нужно двоеточие в восьмой строчке в квадратных скобках?

***Код:***

```py
text = input('Введите текст, 
который вернется написанный 
в обратном порядке\n')
dlina = len(text)
text_new = ''
while text:
    text_new += text[dlina-1]
    text = text[:dlina-1]
    dlina = len(text)
print(text_new)
```

Answer (score 2):

Это срез массива. Вот тут больше инфы о срезах https://pythonz.net/references/named/slice/

Если коротко, то он берет все элементы из массива text по индексам от 0... до dlina-1 (полагаю -1 нужен из-за того что нумерация массива начинается с 0)