# Как работает эта рекурсия в пайтон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, рекурсия, методы

```
def sum(list):
    if list == []:
        return 0
    else: 
        return list[0] + sum(list[1:])

print(sum([1,2,3]))
```

пожалуй самый главный вопрос это - что делает двоеточие в вызове функции? `+ sum(list[1:])`
там где `1:`

Comment: Это срез списка (slice)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для чего нужно двоеточие в квадратных скобках?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119715/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` в индексах списка называется - срез (slice).

Самый базовый пример:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

`a[i:j]` - возвращает все элементы списка начиная с `i`, заканчивая `j-1`

Тогда `a[0:2]` - вернёт первый и второй элемент списка:

```
print(a[0:2]) -> [1, 2]
```

Так же есть сокращенная запись срезов (как и у вас в примере), мы можем не указывать либо начальный индекс `i`, либо конечный индекс `j`, и тогда автоматически будут браться элементы либо с начала (в случае пропуска `i`), либо с конца (в случае пропуска `j`)

Тогда вызов `a[0:2]` будет аналогичен вызову `a[:2]`, а вызов `a[0:3]` аналогичен вызову `a[0:]`, или просто `a`.

Comment: спасибо! Теперь я понял

Comment: Да рекурсия там, рекурсия. Автор имя стандартной функции переопределил, за что положено канделябром.

Comment: @MBo И класс `list` тоже переопределил своей переменной, но внутри функции это не так страшно ибо локальная переменная )

Answer (score 3):

```
def sum(list):
    ...
    return list[0] + sum(list[1:])
```

Дополню всё же, что по сути рекурсия тут сводится к такой формуле

```
сумма(список) = первый элемент списка + сумма(остальные элементы списка)
```

Ну и отдельно тут ещё обработан случай, когда в списке остался один элемент и тогда "остальные элементы списка" - это пустой список. Заодно то, как это тут сделано, нормально позволяет обработать случай, когда список изначально пустой.

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!